# Dealing with a JObject vs a JArray

Tags: c#, json

I have a method which receives this parameter:

```
List<QueueItem> signups
```

This is the class:

```
public class QueueItem
{
  public string Everything{ get; set; } //all the fields in one string 
...
}
```

Everything has a string with all the fields from a Key Value pair object like this...

```js
[{
  "Key": "Partner",
  "Value": "Place"
}, {
  "Key": "FIRST_NAME",
  "Value": "John"
}, {
  "Key": "last_name",
  "Value": "Smith"
}]
```

But this line...

```
var result = signups.Select(x => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(x.Everything));
```

Comes back with this error message:

"Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'"

The solution I've seen is to not cast to JObject and leave it as JArray but that would require changing the rest of the method which checks JObject specific stuff like Properties() etc. I would love to be able to deal with the json as a JObject and keep everything else as is. Is there an efficient way to do that?

Because later I constantly check JObject specific properties like this...

```
var Properties = result.Select(x => x.Properties()).ToArray();
```

Comment: I would just use [`JToken.Parse`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ParseJsonAny.htm) and cast the resulting `JToken` as needed. `JToken` is the base class for both `JObject` and `JArray`...

Comment: Parse takes the json as a string though.  This is a list of objects which includes a string with all the fields.  Don't I have to DeserializeObject() first? Which brings it back to the original problem?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include an example of what's in `Everything`. Basically, if you can successfully do `Deserialize<JObject>(x.Everything)`, you can successfully do `JToken.Parse(x.Everything)` and get a similar result.

Comment: I just added the content of Everything.

Comment: Well, that should deserialize to a `JArray` as the error suggests (the `[]` are the hint there). Since an array doesn't have any really interesting properties, you likely need to iterate through the `JArray` to have any fun with it. Without knowing what you're trying to do with the results, it's hard to answer the question.

Comment: If for some reason you need to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`, for instance to pass `JsonSerializerSettings`, you can always do `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(x.Everything, settings)`

Answer (score 1):

what about deserializing straight to a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`:

```
var pairs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>(x.Everything);
foreach(var kvp in pairs)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Key: {kvp.Key}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Value: {kvp.Value}");
}
```

[KeyValuePair documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: What would be the equivalent of .Properties() for a key value pair object though?

Comment: @John edited to show an example of accessing the properties of a KeyValuePair